# Is there any easy way to set image asset in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have the html template where i image is referenced as `images/logo.gif`

Now in Symfony templates i have to use

`src="{{ asset(['images/', 'logo.gif']|join) }}"`

Is it possible to use something like

`src="{{ asset(['images'])}}/logo.gif`

so that i need not replace all the image tags in html file. Then i can find and replace easily. Othwise i have to manually change all image occurances

Comment: Have you tried `{{ asset('images') }}/logo.gif`? as far as I've seen, the asset function doesn't care if it's a real file or not.

Comment: thanks Carl that worked, i think i was using `asset(['images'])` instead of `asset('images')}`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use this?

```
src="{{ asset('images/logo.gif') }}"
```

EDIT:

I didn't try it but concatenation should work as well:

```
{% set imageDir = 'images/' %}

src="{{ asset(imageDir ~ 'logo.gif') }}"
```

However, it introduces unnecessary complexity. I don't see anything wrong in a hard coded version. You don't change it often.

Comment: But then i have to chnage every image in html file. I don't want to have image name in it. I only want something for in place of `images` something like `$images/logo.gif` so that i can mass replace and my file works